# Stubbing document.ready with Sinonjs

Tags: javascript, sinon

I am trying to stub the `$(function() {})` capabilities of jQuery in my tests but can't figure out how.

I read that I could just write `sinon.stub($.fn, 'ready');` and that would work, but I am getting an error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
  # seating_chart/seating_chart_controller_spec-07e88cd4275ced92864d500e93e46bf2.js:
```

If it makes any difference - I am not including jQuery in my test files. I want to be able to run my tests without jQuery and just stub/mock and functionality I need.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not including jQuery, it's to be expected that `$` (and `$.fn`) are undefined.

`sinon.stub()` only works on existing functions, so you need to at least set up a scaffold for it to be able to work:

```
var $ = { fn : { ready : function() {} } };
...
sinon.stub($.fn, 'ready')
```